# Binary Bomb Lab Assignment Phase 5 - Stuck on a XOR line

Tags: c, assembly, binary, x86-64, binary-bomb

In phase 5 of my bomb lab, I need to input seven integers.

Here's the assembly code for the part I'm stuck on:

```
0x00005555555568cc <+11>:    xor    0x8(%rsp),%esi
0x00005555555568d0 <+15>:    cmp    $0xffffffff,%esi
0x00005555555568d3 <+18>:    jne    0x555555556900 <fun5+63>
```

The value at 0x8(%rsp) is my 7th input, and the value at %esi is my 6th input. I'm stuck on what I should make these inputs to make the cmp line equal so that my code does not jump.

Comment: Which part is unclear? If the result is all 1 bits that means all the bits are different in the two inputs. So just make your inputs the inverse of each other.

Comment: `xor 0x8(%rsp),%esi` sets `%esi` to a^b, where a is the value in `0x8(%rsp)`, b is the value initially in `%esi`, and `^` its bitwise XOR. To make `%esi` compare equal to `0xffffffff`, you need a^b = 0xffffffff. Since XOR is its own inverse, you need a = 0xffffffff^b or, conversely, b = 0xffffffff^a. If these are the only constraints, you can pick any value for a or b and calculate the other.

Answer (score 0):

See [Eric's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77642064/binary-bomb-lab-assignment-phase-5-stuck-on-a-xor-line#comment136879963_77642064): you need `6th_input` `XOR` `7th_input` to be `0xffffffff`. For example, one of them could be `4294967295` and the other `0`.

Presumably you have a 6th input already in which case you can trivially use `bash` to determine what the 7th input must be:

```
sixth=0 # Set your 6th input here.
echo $((4294967295 ^ ${sixth}))
```